# Update SP farm order

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, 2016, patching

I am going to patch my SharePoint 2016 farm 8 SharePoint servers and I have important question

1. Do I need to install the binaries on all servers first then run the config wizard? Or else it doesn't matter and I can run the config wizard on the server once the binaries installation have finished without waiting the other servers!
2. Consider that all binaries have installed on all servers do I need to run config wizard on each server one by one or I can run it in parallel for all servers at the same time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(1)-**  **No**, you need first to install the patch files on all SharePoint servers **then** run the SharePoint Configuration Wizard.

When you run the SharePoint Configuration wizard, it checks first to make sure that all binaries are **installed** and **matched** on all SharePoint Server. 
therefore if one server crosses the farm doesn't have the same patch file installed it will show error message with the mismatched servers and will not **continue** until solving the mismatching servers!!

---

**(2)-** Yes you can run the Config wizard in parallel where the current one will wait to start (at step 1 or 2) until the previous run finish! I explained this in details at [PRODUCT / PATCH INSTALLATION OR SERVER UPGRADE REQUIRED](https://blog.devoworx.net/2016/11/21/product-patch-installation-or-server-upgrade-required/)

> **Note**: it's recommended to start running the Configuration Wizard on
>   the SharePoint Application server that host the Central Administration

Comment: Thank you Mohammed, it's good answer for 1st question, what about the second one?

Comment: Welcome, check the updated answer!